# Access local json data with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile

I am testing a app from the web trying to learn the use of json data in jquery mobile. In the original app, the json data was listed explicitly in the javascript file. I extracted the data  and saved it in a directory in the local drive (same place as the html file and the javascript file). After the change, the page stopped working due to file access problem. I searched google for a whole day but did not find a solution.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
<title>Test data listview</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../download18Dec13/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="../download18Dec13/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../download18Dec13/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</head>

 <!--first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="info-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
             <h1> Information</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="prof-list" data-divider-theme="a" data-      inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--second page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="details-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-  role="button">Go back</a>

         <h1>Employee Details</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
    //assuming this comes from an ajax call
    //alert(window.location.href);
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "data.js");
    var info=$.getJSON('data.js',function(data){
        //alert( "JSON Data: " + data[ 3 ].name );
        //var info=data;
    });

    //var info=data;
        //.done(function() {
                //alert( "second success" );
         //})
        //.fail(function() {
            //alert( "error" );
        //})
        //.always(function() {
                //alert( "complete" );
        //});
    //alert(info.always());
    //alert($.document.url());
    //pageinit event for first page
    //triggers only once
    //write all your on-load functions and event handlers pertaining to page1
    //var info = new Spry.Data.JSONDataSet("data.js");
     //alert(infor[3].name);
      //alert("ffff");
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#info-page", function () {


        //set up string for adding <li/>
        var li = "";
        //container for $li to be added
        $.each(info, function (i, name) {
            //add the <li> to "li" variable
            //note the use of += in the variable
            //meaning I'm adding to the existing data. not replacing it.
            //store index value in array as id of the <a> tag
            li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + name.name + '</a>    </li>';
        });
        //append list to ul
        $("#prof-list").append(li).promise().done(function () {
            //wait for append to finish - thats why you use a promise()
            //done() will run after append is done
            //add the click event for the redirection to happen to #details-page
            $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //store the information in the next page's data
                $("#details-page").data("info", info[this.id]);
                //change the page # to second page. 
                //Now the URL in the address bar will read index.html#details-page
                //where #details-page is the "id" of the second page
                //we're gonna redirect to that now using changePage() method
                $.mobile.changePage("#details-page");
            });

            //refresh list to enhance its styling.
            $(this).listview("refresh");
        });
    });

    //use pagebeforeshow
    //DONT USE PAGEINIT! 
    //the reason is you want this to happen every single time
    //pageinit will happen only once
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#details-page", function () {
        //get from data - you put this here when the "a" wa clicked in the previous page
        var info = $(this).data("info");
        //string to put HTML in
        var info_view = "";
        //use for..in to iterate through object
        for (var key in info) {
            //Im using grid layout here.
            //use any kind of layout you want.
            //key is the key of the property in the object 
            //if obj = {name: 'k'}
            //key = name, value = k
            info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar  field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-  block-b">
    <div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 75%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
        }
        //add this to html
        $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
    });

Json data (To save space, only three items listed):
       {
        {
            "id": 0,
               "age": 31,
                "name": "Avis Greene",
                "gender": "female",
                "company": "Handshake",
                "email": "avisgreene@handshake.com",
                "phone": "+1 (845) 575-2978",
                "address": "518 Forrest Street, Washington, New York, 3579"
        }, {
            "id": 1,
                "age": 31,
                "name": "Dunn Haynes",
                "gender": "male",
                "company": "Signity",
                "email": "dunnhaynes@signity.com",
                "phone": "+1 (829) 454-3806",
                "address": "293 Dean Street, Dante, Oregon, 5864"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "age": 20,
            "name": "Contreras Keith",
            "gender": "male",
            "company": "Overfork",
            "email": "contreraskeith@overfork.com",
            "phone": "+1 (941) 412-2874",
            "address": "166 Broome Street, Norris, Kentucky, 2163"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "age": 27,
            "name": "Hays Schneider",
            "gender": "male",
            "company": "Orbean",
            "email": "haysschneider@orbean.com",
            "phone": "+1 (896) 599-2026",
            "address": "889 Engert Avenue, Staples, Illinois, 9927"
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a JavaScript problem, or a JSON problem you're having.
This is a browser-security problem.

Long story short, you want to run the webpage on your computer/device (ie: directly from your drive to your browser), and then also make AJAX calls from that file, to your hard-drive to get JSON.

Browser makers decided that this would be a very bad idea, to allow you to do keep doing this.
The reasoning is pretty simple...  ...if anybody could make an .html file run on your system, then any JS it asked for could access any file on your computer and send that data to any other computer...  That would be bad.

Anyway, the moral of this particular story is that you need a server.
You can run a server on your local machine, connect to that server from your browser, and then the server can load the page/JSON and send it back to the browser, and everybody's happy.  Then it's the server's job to make sure it's not giving everything away.

Getting a PHP server up and running is very, very easy, these days, if you're on a PC.
Python has an easy server as well.

Comment: Adding to what Norguard just said, you can always use Dropbox's public folder (https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en)  to store statics online. Will be easier than getting a PHP server up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not well formated. Now its well formed.

dada.json file

```
{
"data":[{
    "id": 0,
    "age": 31,
    "name": "Avis Greene",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "Handshake",
    "email": "avisgreene@handshake.com",
    "phone": "+1 (845) 575-2978",
    "address": "518 Forrest Street, Washington, New York, 3579"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "age": 31,
    "name": "Dunn Haynes",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "Signity",
    "email": "dunnhaynes@signity.com",
    "phone": "+1 (829) 454-3806",
    "address": "293 Dean Street, Dante, Oregon, 5864"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "age": 20,
    "name": "Contreras Keith",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "Overfork",
    "email": "contreraskeith@overfork.com",
    "phone": "+1 (941) 412-2874",
    "address": "166 Broome Street, Norris, Kentucky, 2163"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "age": 27,
    "name": "Hays Schneider",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "Orbean",
    "email": "haysschneider@orbean.com",
    "phone": "+1 (896) 599-2026",
    "address": "889 Engert Avenue, Staples, Illinois, 9927"
}]
}


<script> 
$(document).on("pageinit", "#info-page", function () {
   var li = '<li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>';
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (json, status){
        var data = json.data;
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
           $.each(value, function(key, value){                
                if(key == 'name'){
                    li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + key + '" class="info-go">' + value + '</a> </li>';
                }
            })
        })
        $("#prof-list").append(li).trigger('create');
            $("#prof-list").listview('refresh');                
    })
    .success(function(result) {}) 
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {})
    .complete(function() {});
})
</script>
```